# Call JS checkValidity() from Blazor EditForm - Get ElementReference for EditForm

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to use HTMLSelectElement: `checkValidity()` for a Blazor EditForm

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/checkValidity

The reason for doing this is that a Required field is set based on non top-level properties and user input and therefore `editContext.Validate();` does not work. I could perhaps use the experimental `ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator` but since the form knows if it is valid or not this is good enough for me.

In a normal html `form` I can validate it like this:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<form method="post" @ref="_htmlForm" @onsubmit="Submit">
    <InputText @bind-Value="name" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

@code
{
    private string name = "";

    private ElementReference _htmlForm;

    private async Task Submit()
    {
        bool isFormValid = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("isFormValid", _htmlForm);
        if (isFormValid == false)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
<script>
    function isFormValid(formRef) {
        return formRef.checkValidity();
    }
</script>
```

However using a `EditForm` causes the following exception if I try to assign `ref` to a `ElementReference`:

> CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditForm' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ElementReference'

If I use `EditForm` like this:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<EditForm @ref="_editForm" Model="name" OnValidSubmit="Submit" Context="editForm">
    <InputText @bind-Value="name" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>

@code
{
    private string name = "";

    private EditForm _editForm;

    private async Task Submit()
    {
        bool isFormValid = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("isFormValid", _editForm);
        if (isFormValid == false)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I get this exception:

> blazor.webassembly.js?v=rcIWTVNnYus6VWf2Z2U1g_JzlC07Ym02cFjHtI59Xsc:1 crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: Serialization and deserialization of 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderFragment`1[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditContext, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]]' instances is not supported. The unsupported member type is located on type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderFragment`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditContext]'.

I could refactor JS to get HTML Id of the component but it should be possible to get `ElementReference` for a `EditForm`?

Comment: *While capturing component references use a similar syntax to capturing element references, capturing component references isn't a JavaScript interop feature. Component references aren't passed to JavaScript code. Component references are only used in .NET code.* [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-8.0) Your best bet is to probably get the ID of the form.